# Are VCL ListViews ListBox DBGrids full touch aware?

Tags: list, delphi, touch, screens

Since we have tablets with Windows 10 I have decided to use again Delphi XE7 and VCL to develop for this multitouch devices.

I have found `ListView`, `ListBox` and `DBGrid` seem not have a standard behavior with pan and scroll (just PanUp & PanDown, ScrollUp ScrollDown). `DBGrid` does not support touching panning. `ListBox`, seem doesn't control inertial panning like `TListview`... and `ListView` react erratically, sometimes "loose" pannings moving scrollbar but not items list.

Have someone tested this controls on Windows 8.1 or Windows 10 using a multitouch tablet ?. Just load components with, let me say 100 items and try to have a simple vertical smooth scroll / pan using fingers.

All together is kind frustrating, and I cannot focus in develop application which is my task.

Question is: Which is the right component or way to use panning (at least vertical panning / Scrolling) with touch screens and working smooth and without problems ? I thought this components should react to standard actions (like PanUp or PanDown) without need to implement the Gesture Manager and control one by one each touch on screen.  I would like to receive your kind feedback. Thank You

Conclusion:  Many thanks to all who have helped with their comments. My own conclusion is Delphi is not ready to be used **as a RAD** for touching screens. The touching implementation is poor and need too much work for very standard using. Should not be necessary invent the wheel again for a very common and standard controls. Actually there are more mobile device users, than desktop users. Perhaps Embarcadero should decide to pay attention to this matter, and give well finished tools wich meet the OS touch and feel controls.

Let me add the same in FM using TGrid works fine.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something more meaningful. A list of component names does not provide any information about the question itself. Your title should be descriptive enough to have relevance and meaning to future readers here who see it in a list of search results. Thanks.

Comment: Also, all of the components you describe offer far more pan and scroll support than you describe. Have you read the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Using_Gesturing_in_Your_Applications)?

Comment: Forgot to mention - and watched the two videos that are linked at the bottom of [Gesturing Overview](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Gesturing_Overview) in the docs?

Comment: Hello Ken thank you for your advices.  I mean touch aware out of the box.  Have you tested this controls on a Windows 8.1 or 10 with a multitouch tablet ?

Comment: I have with a multitouch laptop display, but not a tablet.

Comment: And have tested a simple form with a ListBox, ListView, dBGrid, and populating them a little, about 100 items ? Just try a simple vertical pan on them and tell me if they work well. For me work... but not well. I have tested it on different tablets.

Comment: Components like `TListBox` and `TDBGrid` do not support "smooth scrolling", no matter what input method is used. We use `TListView` with multi touch with no problems. The `TListView` can be customized. Please provide an example of your ListView and describe what exact problem you seem to be having.

Comment: Hallo Gunter thank you for your reply. Nothing special, Just a TListview assigned using LiveBinding to an Adoquery, and the ListView with the ViewStyle as vsReport. Thats all.  No matter if datasource is a Query or I fill previously the items recursively. Also no matter if items are 100 or 5000. Issues are the same.  Now, we have tablets with Windows Atom Z3735 processor,  have found VCL controls  not have a "normalized"   behavior working with touching screens, which should be desirable. The same for Delphi XE 10 ?  Thank You